# How to start teamspeak server on reboot as specific user

Tags: centos, startup, daemon, teamspeak

Linux version on the server is Centos 7.0.

Teamspeak server runs with this command:

```
./opt/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86/ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

My server doesn't have 100% uptime. Therefore, I want the server program to start automatically using a non root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this solution:

```
crontab -e
i
@reboot /opt/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86/ts3server_startscript.sh restart
<esc>
:wq
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not require `root` privileges at all to start the server, you can use something like

```
sudo -u <username> ./opt/teamspeak3-server_linux-x86/ts3server_startscript.sh start
```

to start it as user `<username>`.

This command line must be placed in a file that is executed during startup.

IIRC there is a file for local stuff named somewhat like `99-local` in `/etc/init.d/`. If not, you could write one yourself using some other startup file as template. To schedule the file for being run during startup, use the following command:

```
chkconfig --level 345 <your file name> on
```

whereas `<your file name>` is relative to `/etc/init.d/`.

Please note that you should specify `sudo` with its full path (eg. `/usr/bin/sudo`) to prevent the possibility of executing another version of `sudo` placed somewhere in the search path and you should resolve the `.` in `./opt/...` (if executed from the root directory, it would be `/opt/...`).